# Proper way to set limit in mongodb on log files

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, log-files, mongodb

It more beginner question.
I trying to set limit on mongo log file in AWS linux instance. 
I found some question that was asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/540423/mongodb-proper-way-to-rotate-logs). And tryed to do that as was suggest from someone for mongo 3.0. Mongo logs sit '/var/log/mongo'. As I understand, because this line in '/etc/mongod.conf':

```
#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongo/mongod.log
```

As described in Mongo docs, that i can use SIGUSR1 signal and get the old log renamed and current switched and delete. So I wrote that, in:

```
"/var/log/mongo/*.log {
    daily
    size 100M
    rotate 5
    compress
    dateext
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /data/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Restarted mongod service. And after couple days I found that mongo logs filled in two files more than 2 gb.So it doesn't work for me. So I don't know what I did wrong? Who can help me?

Thanks!